# Setting up Vue 3, Typescript for unit testing

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3

I created a TodoApp in vue-typescript but I get an error as shown below when doing unit testing. Any idea why I get the error?  Here's my [repo](https://github.com/isogunro/vuets-to-do-app) to see my setup.

[image]

I did go through the documentation but unable to rid the error.  **vue-jest** is in the transform option of my package.

Answer (score 0):

Hewy i did a [small hack](https://github.com/isogunro/vuets-to-do-app/pull/1) on your code, this is not a solution keeping jest as test runner, but maybe can help you to setup a working test environment.